# Powershell: Turn list output into an array of objects or something similar using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I know how to return hashtables, arrays etc from Powershell to c# through PSObjects. In order to use that, I need to return an object from the Powershell script - not just list the output.

But how can I get from a list in Powershell to something structured I can return from the Powershell script?

Think about this simple scenario (for example purposes):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Test
```

And I get something like this output:

```
PS C:\test> Get-ChildItem

Directory: C:\test

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        03.06.2013     14:59          6 test1.txt
-a---        03.06.2013     14:59          5 test2.txt
```

Now I want to take the Name and Length property of each file and return it from the powershell script as some sort of object, I can process with C#.

An example of something I could handle from C# would be this:

```
$a = New-Object psobject -Property @{
   Name = "test1.txt"
   Age = 6
}

$b = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Name = "test2.txt"
    Age = 5
}

$myarray = @()

$myarray += $a
$myarray += $b

Return $myarray
```

**How do I get from Get-ChildItem (or something similar that gives a list) to an array of objects or something similar?**

Please note that this is not about Get-ChildItem specifically, it is just used as an example of something that outputs a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like that should do it:

```
$arr = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name,Length
return $arr
```

If for some reason it doesn't work, try nesting the array in a one array element (using the comma operator)

```
return ,$arr
```

Comment: I like wheels. So...`$arr = (Get-ChileItem | % {[PSCustomObject]@{Name=$_.Name;Lenght=$_.Length}})`

Comment: You're taking the longer route but it is a valid route :)