# Send Powershell from C# and return Array Object from results?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm new to C# and Powershell and looking to run some Powershell from C#. What I would like to do is turn the output from Powershell to an array for use in C#.

The goal would be to send a command such as Get-Process and return the results to C# and display it in a listbox using the listbox.DataSource property.

I've found this: [Turn list output into an array of objects or something similar using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897554/turn-list-output-into-an-array-of-objects-or-something-similar-using-powershell)

I haven't figured out how to utilize the answer for my needs. Keep in mind Get-Process is just an example. There's a plethora of other data that would be nice to dump to an array and pass into C# to minimize the amount of code that would be otherwise required to convert the output into an array. If there's no other option I'll go that route. For my project I'd like to stick to a listbox output for remote applications.

I thank everyone in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get data back from PowerShell in C# as a Collection.  Just use the LINQ ToArray() method on the collection returned to get an array e.g.:

```
PSObject[] results = pipeline.Invoke().ToArray();
```